# How to display all rows with same ID in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

My Index page displays all rows from an Azure SQL Database. When I click a row I get redirected to a unique URL with a QR code for that URL and it also displays the data for only that row. Each row has it's own unique ID, but also a truckID. The truckID is for a driver who can "own" several rows of data, so I want to show every row with the same truckID after a row is clicked.

This is what I've got so far:

MODEL

```
        namespace QR
        {
            using System;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
            using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
            using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
            using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

            [Table("data")]
            public partial class data
            {
                [Required]
                [StringLength(50)]
                public string Contract { get; set; }

                [StringLength(50)]
                public string Sort { get; set; }

                public int? Report { get; set; }

                public double? InputKG { get; set; }

                public double? OutputKG { get; set; }

                public double? Recovery { get; set; }

                public double? Si { get; set; }

                public double? Cu { get; set; }

                public double? Mn { get; set; }

                public double? Mg { get; set; }

                public double? Zn { get; set; }

                public double? Cr { get; set; }

                public double? Fe { get; set; }

                public double? Pb { get; set; }

                public int? truckID { get; set; }

                [Key]
                public int ID{ get; set; }

            }
        }
```

VIEW (after a row is clicked from Index)

```
        @model QR.data

        @{
            ViewBag.Title = "Details";
            Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
        }

        <h2>QR code</h2>
            <img src="/Home/BarcodeImage?barcodeText=@Request.Url.OriginalString"/>

        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contract)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Sort)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Report)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.InputKG)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OutputKG)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Recovery)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Si)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Cu)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Mn)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Mg)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Zn)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Cr)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Fe)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Pb)
                </th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Contract)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Sort)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Report)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.InputKG)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.OutputKG)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Recovery)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Si)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Cu)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Mn)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Mg)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Zn)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Cr)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Fe)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Pb)
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p>
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
        </p>
```

CONTROLLER

```
  public ActionResult Details(int? id)
       {
           if (id == null)
           {
               return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
           }
           data data= db.data.Find(id);
           if (data == null)
           {
               return HttpNotFound();
           }
           return View(data);
       }
```

And on the Index I have this link:

```
        @Html.ActionLink("QR", "Details", new { id = item.ID})
```

Help?

Comment: I don't see how you're trying to incorporate your TruckID into the data/view anywhere...  your query could be something like `data data = db.data.Where(x => x.TruckID = YourTruckIDVariable).ToList()`, but your view needs some work as well...

Answer (score 2):

With this answer I presume two things:

- `db` is a `DbContext` and has a property called `data` which is a `DbSet<data>`
- You don't have any other models for your data, only the `data` class

If the above is true, here's what you should do:

In the controller:

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    data data = db.data.Find(id);
    if (data == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    var groupedData = db.data.Where(d => d.truckID == data.truckID).ToList();

    return View(groupedData);
}
```

In your view (Details)

```
// This is after declaring the table headers
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Contract)
        </td>

        // Fill in rest of the td rows as you did 

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Pb)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

This *should* display all of the rows correctly.

Also, this is just for readability, but it is really important, **capitalize your class names**, i.e. it should be `public partial class Data` not `data`.

Comment: Your presumptions are correct, but the code displays an empty table on the Details page. Do you have any idea why? Also, how should the Details page know what truckID rows to display?

Comment: Here's what I thought: the index page shows the records - identified by `id`. There are several rows with different `id`-s but same `truckID`-s. My solution finds the row with the selected `id`, then uses the `truckID` of that record to gather the rest of the data. I do realise, that I missed a `.ToList()` from the end of `db.data.Where(d => d.truckID == data.truckID)`. Add that or just copy my updated answer and the rows should show up.

Comment: Correct, Index shows each row with a unique ID. Each row has also a truckID, but several rows can have the same truckID. But the view remains empty after implementing your code. Is there some other code you could need a snippet of perhaps?

Comment: So an update: 

`return View(db.data.Where(c => c.truckID == 100).ToList());`
This works and retrieves all rows with truckID 100. So I guess my question is how can I preserve the truckID from Index to Details?

Comment: Can you check the value of `data.truckID` with the debugger?

Comment: I figured it out. `var data = db.data.Where(a => a.truckID == id);` and `return View(hydrodata.ToList());` in the controller and `@Html.ActionLink("QR", "Details", new { id = item.truckID })` on the Index did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

You didn't get any error on this statement ?

```
data data= db.data.Find(id);
```

I think it has to be like this

```
data data= db.data.Find(i=>i.ID == id);
```

and  I supposed you were using foreach loop to print all of the data and in that loop you have that @Html.ActionLink.

Comment: No errors. And yes, the ActionLink on the Index has a foreach loop `@foreach (var item in Model)`